# AutoCompleteView sending data to RecycleView

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, autocompletetextview

I'm  working on `autocompleteview`, which brings up the surges according to what was registered in Firebase. I want that when typing and showing the options I can click on the suggestion that appears and send it to the `recycleViewer` at the bottom.

[prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qth34.png)

However my problem is in the recording of the data inside the recycle. When doing the second search, instead of joining the previous one, the new one replaces the old one.

```
public class NewListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

private CollectionReference docRef =
        db.collection("data")
                .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .collection("product");

private AutoCompleteTextView ac_tv_Product;
private AutoCompleteProductAdapter autoCompleteProductAdapter;

private RecyclerView rvShoppingList;
private RecycleViewerListAdapter recycleViewerListAdapter;

private List<ProductItem> productItemsList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_list);

    getDataFromFire();

    ac_tv_Product = findViewById(R.id.ac_tv_Product);
    rvShoppingList = findViewById(R.id.rvShoppingList);
    rvShoppingList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

    autoCompleteProductAdapter = new AutoCompleteProductAdapter(this, productItemsList);
    ac_tv_Product.setAdapter(autoCompleteProductAdapter);

    recycleViewerListAdapter = new RecycleViewerListAdapter(productItemsList);

    ac_tv_Product.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            addItemToRecycle(position);
        }
    });
}

private void addItemToRecycle(int position) {
    rvShoppingList.setAdapter(recycleViewerListAdapter);
   Log.e("ItemCount", String.valueOf(recycleViewerListAdapter.getItemCount()));

}

private void getDataFromFire() {
    docRef.get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (isFinishing() || isDestroyed()) return;
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d("Deu certo", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            String name = document.getString("name");
                            String local = document.getString("location");

                            productItemsList.add(new ProductItem(name, local));
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d("deu errado", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

**RecyclerView Adapter**

```
public class RecycleViewerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewerListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<ProductItem> items;

public RecycleViewerListAdapter(List<ProductItem> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_list_recycle, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tvRecycleName.setText(items.get(position).getProductName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView tvRecycleName, tvRecycleValue, tvRecycleLocal;


    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvRecycleName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRecycleName);
        tvRecycleValue = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRecycleValue);
        tvRecycleLocal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRecycleLocal);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Since it's Java and Firestore, most likely this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) will help.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, to solve my problem, I needed to see two things.

The first refers to removing the `RecycleViewerListAdapter` from within the `onItemClick`, so that it does not replace what is on the screen.

```
    ac_tv_Product.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            addItemToRecycle(position);
        }
    });

    recycleViewerListAdapter = new RecycleViewerListAdapter(teste);
    rvShoppingList.setAdapter(recycleViewerListAdapter);
}
```

The second is directly in the `Recycle Row` xml, as it needs to be as a `wrap parent` for more than one to appear in the list.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```